# utf-8 string similarity in postgresql 10.1

Tags: string, postgresql, utf-8, ascii, similarity

:) I'm trying to find strings similarity in PostgreSQL 10.1.

I use the extensions `unaccent` and `pg_trgm` and enabled them with:

```
create extension unaccent;
create extension pg_trgm;
```

The problem is that `pg_trgm` does not provide utf8 support. So if I execute:

```
select similarity('כפיר','כפיר');
```

it returns similarity of zero.

I decided to convert that string to an `iso-8859-8` encoding which supports Hebrew and English, the languages that I use in this case.

But first I want to `unaccent` the string, so if I have `כפיר - ƒ` it will first be converted to `כפיר - f` so it will be properly converted to the desired character encoding.

So `select unaccent('כפיר - ƒ');` does return the proper results.

So unfortunately executing:

```
select convert(unaccent('כפיר - ƒ'),'UTF8','ISO_8859_8');
```

returns

> [42883] ERROR: function convert(text, unknown, unknown) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 8

When I check the documentation at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html regarding `convert()` function it requires a string.

If I try to cast something as string, I get that `type "string" does not exist`

OK. So working with unaccent is the first issue that I need to resolve (and maybe the only issue). What I did next returned proper results without me seeing the proper string in hebrew.

What I mean is this..

Executing `select convert('כפיר','UTF-8','ISO_8859_8');` returns

```
4 B 00000000  EB F4 E9 F8                                        ëôéø
```

and casting it to text with `select convert('כפיר','UTF8','ISO_8859_8')::text;` returns `\xebf4e9f8`

I'm guessing these are the write characters and because of the change in encoding I don't see the actual Hebrew characters. am I wrong to assume that ? that's the 2nd issue.

So if I don't use accent and execute:

```
select similarity(convert('כפייר עזר','UTF8','ISO_8859_8')::text, convert('כפיר','UTF8','ISO_8859_8')::text);
```

it returns a similarity of 0.5 which is OK.

To sum up, my questions are:

1. How to cast `unaccent` properly to be able to use it in `convert`
2. Am I casting my utf-8 Hebrew string properly to ASCII?
3. Am I trying to resolve the issue the right way - is there a different extension for similarity function that supports utf-8?
4. I also want to remove any character that is not alphanumeric from the string before I do execute the similarity function in order to get better similarity results based on my needs. I think about using regular expressions about converting the string to ASCII. something like: `regexp_replace('string', '\W+', '', 'g')`. Is that the way to go? Is there a regexp_replace that supports utf8 ?

Thank You!

Comment: @CaiusJard - ERROR: function convert(character varying, unknown, unknown) does not exist

Comment: Hmm, strange. I have `server_encoding` set to `UTF8` and `lc_collate` and `lc_ctype` set to `de_DE.UTF-8`, and I get 1 for `SELECT similarity('כפיר','כפיר')`. I am running on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so the solution was simple.

needed to convert it to byte-array (`bytea`) and then back to text.
and regarding the regular expression replace, I should have used the specific characters that I wanted to remove instead of using `\W+`.

so the solution for my case is:

```
   select
  similarity(convert(unaccent(regexp_replace(lower('string'), '[.,''׳`"-]', '', 'g'))::bytea,'UTF8','ISO_8859_8')::text,
             convert(unaccent(regexp_replace(lower('string'), '[.,''׳`"-]', '', 'g'))::bytea,'UTF8','ISO_8859_8')::text)
```